# JMeter: the same UUID between several samplers

Tags: random, jmeter, uuid

How can a Jmeter thread group with several HTTP requests uses the same UUID value per thread?

I've tried to create 'user defined variables' element with `${__UUID}` and java preprocessor with `vars.put("uuid", UUID.randomUUID().toString())`; (independently)

[image: thread group]

but every http request in the same thread using its own UUID.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Move the java PreProcessor as the **child** of the first [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request)(start session) and then call it as `${uuid}` in all requests to get only one UUID value.

Another option is without code: Add [User Parameters](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#User_Parameters) as PreProcessor of the first [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request)(start session) with Name as `uuid2` and Value `${__UUID()}` and you can use `${uuid2}` to get only one UUID value.

Comment: Yes, this is the solution. Just one addition from my side. There is one checkbox "Update Once per Iteration" which you have to check for this to work. This might have changed based on the jmeter version etc.

Answer (score 0):

JMeter Variables are local and individual for each thread (see [ThreadLocal](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadLocal.html) concept for details) so in order to create a random GUID structure you need:

- Execute this function only once (optional, but nice to have). For instance it can be done using [If Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/six-tips-for-jmeter-if-controller-usage) with condition set to something like:

  ```
  ${__groovy(ctx.getThreadNum() == 0 && vars.getIteration() == 1)}
  ```
- Make function execution result available to all JMeter Threads. There are multiple ways of doing it, the easiest is converting it to JMeter Property via [setProperty() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__setProperty)
- Refer to the generated GUID using [__P() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P) as `${__P(uuid,)}` where required

This way you will be able to access the same GUID value from different threads or even thread groups.

Demo:

[image: UUID Property Demo]

Answer (score 0):

you cannot reuse the generated ${__UUID}, but you can always generate it via JavaScript function (it allows to reuse the result):
`${__javaScript(function s4(){return Math.floor((1 + Math.random()) * 0x10000).toString(16).substring(1);} s4() + s4() + '-' + s4() + '-' + s4() + '-' + s4() + '-' + s4() + s4() + s4();, var_for_reuse)}`